# Render multiple React components into a single DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to render multiple modals into a single ReactDOM element. Here's the HTML structure that React renders to.

```
<body>
    <div id="modal-socket"></div> // Insert multiple here
    <div id="wrapper">
        // Other content goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

There's a long story behind why I need to render multiple components into #modal-socket but I want to do something akin to this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<AddMeasurableModal />, document.getElementById("modal-socket"));
ReactDOM.render(<AddMeasurableModal />, document.getElementById("modal-socket"));
ReactDOM.render(<AddMeasurableModal />, document.getElementById("modal-socket"));
```

Obviously this replaces the current content of #modal-socket on each render call.. So I don't get my end result. Boo.

Did a search and found a few answers on it but none meet my needs.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you told in a comment, the dynamic way would be something like this
Inside of a main component you could do:

Imagine having an array like:

```
let myArray = [
  {
     prop1: 'hello world'
  },
  {
     prop1: 'Hey there!'
  }
]

//Then in the render function (you can put that array into the state or something)
render(){
      return (
         <div>
           {myArray.map((entry,index) => {
              return <AddMeasurableModal key={index} {...entry} />
           })}
         </div>
      )
}
```

this will create as many `AddMeasurableModal` components as there are entrys in the `myArray` variable and add every property stored as props onto the component (In this case, every `AddMeasurableModal` component has access to the `this.props.prop1` value, because of the `{...entry}` spread syntax)

Notice how I only put `myArray.map()` into the render function inside of `{}`?
React renders every array of components without further configuration inside of the render function. And `Array.map()` returns an array. Just make sure to return only valid react elements! When doing this, don't forget to add a uniqe `key` prop to each element to avoid warnings.

EDIT: in this case, the `key` prop is the current index in the array, but when fetching data from a server I would recommend to use a uniqe id from the database or something to avoid rendering bugs.
If you don't want to map over an array, you can just set a number of components and then loop over them, creating an array of components and put them into the render function.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your multiple modals into 1 container and render that, eg:

```
let modals = (
  <div>
    <AddMeasurableModal />
    <AddMeasurableModal />
    <AddMeasurableModal />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(modals, document.getElementById("modal-socket"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps massively.

Can you think of how you'd do this dynamically?

Comment: Thats pretty simple tho, I'll create an example for you